# confusing behavior with python import

Tags: python

Hi, there.

I have two files:

*a.py:*

```
print('in a')
import b

print('var')
VAR = 1

def p():
    print('{}, {}'.format(VAR, id(VAR)))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    VAR = -1
    p()
    b.p() # Where does this VAR come from?
```

*b.py:*

```
print('in b')
import a

def p():
    a.p()
```

I don't understand why there're two different VARs, which is supposed to the same.

If I move the 'main' block to another file, everything works well, i.e, there is only one VAR.

*c.py:*

```
import a
import b

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a.VAR = -1
    a.p()
    b.p()
```

So my question is:

Why do the last two lines of a.py print different results?

Don't they print the same VAR variable in a.py?

BTW, I'm using python 2.7 on win7.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to read up on [global variables](http://docs.python.org/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-rules-for-local-and-global-variables-in-python)? To quote:

> *If a variable is assigned a new value anywhere within the function’s body, it’s assumed to be a local. If a variable is ever assigned a new value inside the function, the variable is implicitly local, and you need to explicitly declare it as ‘global’.*

Edit: to elaborate, here's what happens (leaving out `c.py` for clarity):

1. File `a.py` is executed.
2. File `b.py` is imported, and in turn imports `a.py` again.
3. Via b's import, `VAR` is defined in with a value of 1. This ends b`s import.
4. The `__main__` part in `a.py` is executed *in its own scope*; `VAR` is set to -1 there, and `p()` is ran: this displays -1, as `VAR` was just set to.
5. Then `b.p()` is executed, which in turn runs `a.p()`. Because `VAR` from the perspective of `b.py` (different scope) still has a value of 1, the print statement just outputs 1.

You'll also notice that the id's are different in both print statements: this is because the `VAR`'s live in a different scope, and are not connected in any way. **They are disconnected because `__main__` lives in a different, anonymous scope**: the scope in which the Python interpreter executes. This is briefly discussed in the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/__main__.html#module-__main__).

Comment: Hi, jro.
I didn't do any assignment in functions.
All p() funtions just print the same variable, VAR. (In my opinion)
But it turns out to be two different variables, since they don't have same address or even don't have same value.

Comment: Then why is there only one `VAR` in `c.py`? Why does b.py have its own VAR in `a.py` case but not in `c.py` case?